# Pattern matching on constructor wildcard?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

If I have a constructor which is:

```
data Garage = Gar String
```

if I want to test whether a type is equal to my garage type I would do something like this:

```
(==(Gar _)) (Gar "g")
```

However, the compiler complains about the underscore. If I replace this with `"g"` it returns `True`. Is there a way so that I can compare with a wildcard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why doesn't your code work?**

It looks like you want to pattern match, but actually you're calling the function `==` with arguments `Gar _` and `Gar "g"`.  So Haskell gets confused and says something like "Pattern syntax in expression context: _".

**How can it be fixed?**

You can:

1. add `deriving Eq` to the end of the data declaration, or
2. implement `Eq` yourself:

   ```
   instance Eq Garage where
       (Gar l) == (Gar r) = l == r
   ```

**Is it possible to pattern match against constructor wildcards?** (for completeness)

Yes, here's a nonsense function:

```
f :: Garage -> Int
f (Gar "abc") = 12
f (Gar _) = 4
```

This would probably be more useful with a datatype that had multiple constructors, though.

Comment: Mog, if it's a `_`, it won't be used.

Answer (score 2):

you want to do pattern match, like this:

```
case x of
   Gar _ -> True
   _     -> False
```

if you want it as function, then add somsthing like

```
isGarage (Gar _) = True
isGarage _       = False
```

Comment: Yeh but I desire to return this from a function call

Comment: you can do that, it's expression and it's result can be passed/returned as any other value

Comment: that only returns a boolean, i desire to return the function which does the equality- not the result of the equality

Comment: why not to pass "isGarage" to your code? it's function after all, and can be passed as argument to another function or expression

Comment: If you want ta predicate function like this in general you can use `DataConstructor {}` no matter how many params the constructor has :)

Comment: isGarage function is use less as it will always return `True`. Its type is `Garage -> Bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question assumes that you'll need to do run-time type checking in Haskell, but that's not necessary. Haskell will ensure all your types are correct at compile time, so a function which checks whether data is part of your `Garage` data type is not needed and wouldn't work:

```
justPrintGarages (Gar x) = print x -- if the argument is a Garage, print its content
justPrintGarages _ = return ()     -- if it's anything else, do nothing.
```

If we ask ghci what type `justPrintGarages` has, it will tell us

```
printGarages :: Garage -> IO ()
```

Yikes! Our function that was supposed to tell us whether we had a garage only works on garages??? Yup. That's because Haskell deliberately stops you from mixing types up, because it's a quagmire of runtime errors. Static typing is your friend. Static typing takes away a world of pain. Because of static typing, you can't define

```
printGaragesAndShebangs (Gar x) = print x
printGaragesAndShebangs ('#':'!':xs) = putStr xs
printGaragesAndShebangs _ = return ()
```

You'll get a type error. You can't just treat `String`s and `Garage`s the same.

If you want to mix garages and strings, here's the way to do it, keeping type safety:

```
data GarageStringInt = GsiG Garage | GsiS String | GsiI Int
```

(`GarageStringInt` is a horrible name and so are `GisG` etc, but if you need this in your code it'll represent something sensible (I hope) and you can give it a name that describes what it represents.)

Now we can write

```
printGaragesAndShebangs :: GarageStringInt -> IO ()
printGaragesAndShebangs (GsiG (Gar x)) = print x
printGaragesAndShebangs (GsiS ('#':'!':xs)) = putStr xs
printGaragesAndShebangs _ = return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

A function like

```
isGarage (Gar _) = True
isGarage _       = False
```

is pretty useless as it has type `Garage -> Bool`. So it will always return `True` for `Garage` type and type check failure will occur for any other type.

I think patter matching would be sufficient for your requirement. But just to show that you can have such kind of function using type classes if you know the types you will be acting on. So possibly if you know you will be getting values from a given set of types then you can do something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
data Garage = Gar String

class IsGarage a where
    isGarage :: a -> Bool
    isGarage _ = False

instance IsGarage Garage where
    isGarage _ = True

instance IsGarage [Char]
```

In ghci

```
*Main> :t isGarage 
isGarage :: IsGarage a => a -> Bool
*Main> isGarage "3"
False
*Main> isGarage (Gar "2")
True
```